# How to make the a database field accept just one value for an user

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I'm trying to associate a user with a paypal account, and just one.  Which means that if there is a value on that field, the post request should return "There is already a value there" or simply don't work (Return status code 400).

I've tried using the UniqueTogetherValidator in the serializer and use and ID as well. The problem with this approach is that it requires an 'id' field in the post request which is not generated yet (The id is auto-generated by the framework).

Here is what I'm trying with my serializer implementation

```
class PaypalAffiliateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # id = serializers.ReadOnlyField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = PaypalAffiliate
        validators = [
            UniqueTogetherValidator(
                queryset=PaypalAffiliate.objects.all(),
                fields=['paypal', 'id']
            )
        ]
        fields = ('paypal', 'id')
```

and here is my model

```
class PaypalAffiliate(models.Model):
    paypal = models.EmailField()
    affiliate = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paypal

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('paypal', 'affiliate')
```

And here is my view

```
class PaypalAffiliateViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                             mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                             viewsets.GenericViewSet,
                             mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                             mixins.ListModelMixin):
    queryset = PaypalAffiliate.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PaypalAffiliateSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(affiliate=self.request.user)
        return queryset

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(affiliate=self.request.user)

    def perform_update(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(affiliate=self.request.user)
```

How can I make the PayPal email field accept just one value for every user?

Comment: Why not use a `OneToOneField` for the relation to `User`?

Comment: @DanielHepper, I think it will override it when user update that mean old onetoone relation will be replaced

Comment: I've already tried that. It doesn't achieve the results I'm looking for.

Comment: "it doesn't achieve the results I'm looking for" isn't an explanation. It's exactly what you're looking for, so please explain what precisely didn't work.

Comment: @dirkgroten So even tho I was using OneToOneField relationship instead of the ForeignKey relation, I'm still able to link a user with two (or more) PayPal addresses.

Comment: That's not possible. If it's a 1-to-1 field, one `User` can only have one `PaypalAffiliate`.

Comment: Should I use the OneToOne field relationship on the paypal field instead of the affiliate field? @dirkgroten

Comment: How if we set unique=True for each fields?

Comment: @ToanQuocHo setting `unique=True` on a foreign key defeats the purpose of fk (it makes for ugly reverse relationship queries) and using one-to-one is the point.

Comment: @Octavian no, it should be the `affiliate` field that's a OneToOneField. The `PayPal` field should probably be `unique` as Toan suggested, unless multiple users share the same PayPal email address.

Comment: Note that you'll still be able to make a post request for the same user: it'll just update the PayPal address to the latest one (replacing the old one).

Comment: What will happen with the old data if I change the field from foreign key to one to one field?

Answer (score 1):

If you simply do `unique=True` on field then it should work it  will raise `IntegrityError` in the serializer

```
class PaypalAffiliate(models.Model):
    paypal = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    affiliate = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can catch the `IntegrityError` and return your desired response.

**Update**

If you want at most one `PaypalAffilate` record per user as mentioned use `OneToOneField`

```
class PaypalAffiliate(models.Model):
    paypal = models.EmailField()
    affiliate = OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Your view is also wrong I did not try using Mixins you did but you should do it like this passing data to serializer calling `is_valid()` for your validation

```
serializer = PaypalAffiliateSerializer(data=request.data)
if serializer.is_valid():
  # return 200 OK here
else:
  #return serializer.errors
```

Refer [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/)

Comment: I don't see any errors in there and I can still make the POST request even tho there is a value there already.

Comment: Are you calling `serialzer.is_valid()` then? Post your view

Comment: Do you want to avoid the same email address being re-used for different users? Or do you want to avoid one user having two different PayPal email addresses? It's not clear what you mean by "there is a value there already".

Comment: @dirkgroten I want to avoid the same user having two different PayPal email addresses.

Comment: @YugandharChaudhari I've edited the question and added the code in the view.

Comment: Then as Daniel mentioned, use a OneToOne relationship.